Laplace-type integral on the complex plane of the error function
Let $t \in \mathbb{R}$. I am looking for a way to compute the following integral
$$I_{\alpha}(t) := \int_{\Im(v) > t} \mathrm{erf} \left( \frac{\sqrt{\pi \alpha}}{2i}v\right) \ \exp(-\pi \ \alpha|v|^2) \   e^{- 4\ \pi \ \alpha t\ \Im (v)} dv \wedge d\overline{v},$$
where $\alpha > 0$ and $\mathrm{erf}$ denotes the holomorphic error function, which verifies
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \mathrm{erf}(z) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \exp(-z^2).$$
Thank you for your help.

If there is a hope to get a result it would be to go back to infinite integrals
$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \theta (y) \left(\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } e^{-4 \pi  a t y-\pi  a \left(x^2+y^2\right)} \left(\int_{- \infty }^{\infty } \frac{e^{-\frac{\xi ^2}{2}} \theta (\xi ) \theta (x-\xi )}{\sqrt{2 \pi }} \, d\xi +\int_{- \infty }^{\infty } \frac{\theta (\eta ) e^{-\frac{1}{2} (x+i \eta )^2} \theta (y-\eta )}{\sqrt{2 \pi }} \, d\eta \right) \, dx\right) \, dy$$
where the $\theta$-distribution replaces the bounds and Fubini and linear transforms can be used to simplify the integrands.

Thank you for your answer. I didn't manage to get an explicit expression of the integral using your formula, maybe I'll have to settle with the asymptotic behavior for $t$ big but I am not sure that it will be sufficient.
